# How to Sort a multilevel XML depending on a specific attribute which is present in each tag of XML?

Tags: xml, sorting

I have an XML which contains various tags and the good thing is each tag has an attribute called "id" which may not be unique. I need to sort this XML in such a way that Tags on the same level should be sorted based on the "id" attribute.

I am new to this thing and do not really have much knowledge about XSLT and it seems overly complex. Is there some other way to achieve the required conversion?

Sample Input XML

```
<parent id="p2" name="a">
    <child id="c2" name="z"/>
    <child id="c1" name="y"/>
</parent>
<parent id="p1" name="b">
    <child id="c1" name="w"/>
    <child id="c2" name="x"/>
</parent>
```

Expected Output XML

```
<parent id="p1" name="b">
    <child id="c1" name="w"/>
    <child id="c2" name="x"/>
</parent>
<parent id="p2" name="a">
    <child id="c1" name="y"/>
    <child id="c2" name="z"/>
</parent>
```

Note- The actual XML is very big and has many levels. I need to apply the sorting at each level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) for XML manipulation (I also happen to maintain it). You can sort all the `child` elements by their `id` in all the `parent` elements by the following code:

```
open file.xml ;
for //parent xmove &{ sort :k @id child } into . ;
save :b ;
```

The special `&{ ... }` construct is needed because otherwise nodes in a nodelist are always returned in the document order.